# dynamically plotting with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

i'm new to ggplot and i'm trying to automatically plot multiple subset of the data to different pdf files , but i'm encoutering an error and need your help.

that's my code :

```
library(ggplot2)
t=read.table("../All.txt",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names( t ) <- c("A","C","G","T","(A-T)/(A+T)","(G-C)/(G+T)","(A+T)/(G+C)","accession","Phylum","Order","Class")
    phy=unique(c(t$Phylum))
    for (x in phy){ 
    if(x=="???:???")
    {
        x="unknown"
    }
    pdf(paste(x,".pdf") , width=25, height=15)
    test<-subset(t, Phylum==x)
    dat <- melt(test, measure=c("A", "C" , "G" , "T" , "(A-T)/(A+T)", "(G-C)/(G+T)","(A+T)/(G+C)"))
    ggplot(dat, aes(Class,value , color=variable))  + geom_boxplot() +geom_jitter()   +  facet_grid(variable~., scales="free_y")
    }
```

the error is :

```
argument implies differing number of row: 0,1
```

how can i fix this error? thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted my original answer, and started a new:

```
t <- structure(list(A = 0.286945, C = 0.322006, G = "0.1473610.2436880.081520-0.4466031.130529NC_000846", T = "Chordata", `(A-T)/(A+T)` = "Rheiformes", `(G-C)/(G+T)` = "Aves", `(A+T)/(G+C)` = 0.39562, accession = "0.1334170.0917400.3792240.021160-0.0884933.441356NC_000857", Phylum = "Arthropoda", Order = "Diptera", Class = "Insecta"), .Names = c("A", "C", "G", "T", "(A-T)/(A+T)", "(G-C)/(G+T)", "(A+T)/(G+C)", "accession", "Phylum", "Order", "Class"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

If I run your code, it runs without a warning message, though no plot was saved as did not specified `dev.off` at the end of the loop. You could upload your data file to eg. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

---

**UPDATE:** based on demo data file

Thanks for uploading a sample dataset! I run a modified version of your code (to be able to save the plots in pdf) which run without error/warning:

```
t=read.table("txt-part.txt", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names( t ) <- c("A","C","G","T","(A-T)/(A+T)","(G-C)/(G+T)","(A+T)/(G+C)","accession","Phylum","Order","Class")
phy=unique(t$Phylum)

for (x in phy){ 
    if(x != "???:???") {
    test<-subset(t, Phylum==x)
    dat <- melt(test, measure=c("A", "C" , "G" , "T" , "(A-T)/(A+T)", "(G-C)/(G+T)","(A+T)/(G+C)"))
    p <- ggplot(dat, aes(Class,value , color=variable))  + geom_boxplot() +geom_jitter()   +  facet_grid(variable~., scales="free_y")
    ggsave(paste(x,".pdf"), p, width=25, height=15)
    }}
```

I have got 2 pdf files as expected on your sample data set. If it does not run on the whole data set, I have no idea of the problem without checking the original data file. Maybe others do! :)

Comment: hello , first of all thank you for your help, i tried your option , but the same error appeared.  what do you mean with an example ? and how do i use this function (dput) to help you in resolving my problem ?

Comment: @abd replace read.table() with the output of dput(t) in your question

Comment: @abd: could you please post the output of `dput(t)` or if the output would be really large than upload some example data (part of your *txt* file) somewhere? I made some expreiment with your code on the *diamonds* dataset and your code seemed fine.

Comment: hello , that's a part of my txt file , it's the same thing generated from the dput function : 
0.286945 0.322006 0.147361 0.243688 0.081520 -0.446603 1.130529 NC_000846 Chordata   Rheiformes   Aves

   
0.395620 0.133417 0.091740 0.379224 0.021160 -0.088493 3.441356 NC_000857 Arthropoda   Diptera   Insecta

Comment: how can i upload a text file , because like this you wont be able to understand how the data is arranged ,
in each row there is 11 column(variable) , but they won't appear good here , if there is no way to upload a txt file : 
each 11 value make 1 row

Comment: Hello, i uploaded a part of the txt file on mediafire and that's the link : http://www.mediafire.com/?mnj26kp4bv5lcr5 , thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Hello , this fixed my problem , thank you very much , but i run the script and print phy , it gives mt 25 diffrent value , but when i run the code it only generate 15 pdf , why is this ????

Comment: @abd: do you have any warning/error messages? Also, please paste the output of `phy` to make things clear.

Comment: i did paste the output of phy , it's printing all the phylum , and there count is 25 , but how can i make the script wait me to press a key before closing the console :S , i'm not able to read the error :|

Comment: hello , i managed to take a screen shot of the error , i will upload the image for you , and if needed i will upload the txt file that contain all the data . 
http://www.mediafire.com/?3m3mataw9nlzm1m

Comment: @abd: the error is caused by empty data frames after the `subset` as I can see from the error message. But you should upload the data to make things clear and also please give details about the `if(x=="???:???") x="unknown"` part of your code! That might cause the error also.

Comment: hello ,concerning the if that your talking about , i made it because there is some of the phyulum(1) that are not completed and are written like this ???:???. and concerning the empty subsets,i will send you the full data : 
http://www.mediafire.com/?2nrs14lftrcpl29 
thnx in advance

Comment: @daroczig: hello, did you found what's making the error in the script??? i wasn't able to fix it, :S

Comment: @abd: your `if` condition caused the error. See my updated answer (which excludes the specified *Phylum*).

Comment: @daroczig:ok then , thank you alot , it did fix everything :) , i have another question in another issue , should i ask you here ? or should i open a new question to discuss ??

Comment: @abd: you are very welcome! And to your question: post a new question please :)